# How to append new columns on the side not the bottom

Tags: python

I made a python script that takes a file with a lot of columns and extract and copy (into a new file) the two columns that I need. However, once or twice a month I will need to add additional columns to the same (new) file, but I need to add them to the side of the current columns, not to the bottom. how can I modify the script to do that?

These are some samples of input files.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63216126/file5.txt

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63216126/file6.txt

Here is the code that I wrote.

```
import sys
import re

filetoread = sys.argv[1]
filetowrite = sys.argv[2]

newfile = str(filetowrite) + ".txt"

openold = open(filetoread,"r")
opennew = open(newfile,"a")

rline = openold.readlines()

number = int(len(rline))
start = 0

for i in range (len(rline)) :
    if "2theta" in rline[i] :
        start = i

for line in rline[start + 1 : number] :
    words = line.split()
    word1 = words[1]
    word2 = words[2]
    opennew.write (word1 + " " + word2 + "\n")

openold.close()
opennew.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use.. [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module with `delimiter = '\t'` if you're using tabs.

Refer to answers for [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376236/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-of-data-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I have try to add te cvs as suggested, and honestly I can make it work, it keeps adding the columns at the bottom instead of the side. Also, about similar answers use a handler, which I do not see how o use here. I am new with python, and I think it is really simple to use for what I need, however, this time I can figure out how to use the csv.